# Are stealthed opponents visible when capturing altars on Twisted Treeline?

Tags: league-of-legends

When playing on the new [Twisted Treeline](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Twisted_Treeline) map, I noticed that some champions remain stealthed whilst capturing the [altars](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Altar). Do they remain invisible to the enemy or can they be seen?

Comment: When you say stealthed, do you mean hidden in the fog or actually stealthed like twitch/eve? The altars grant vision if you control them similar to a regular ward.

Comment: The altars ignore fog of war (give vision always, like permanent normal sight wards)

Answer (score 2):

They remain stealthed. Altars don't give vision like the Towers.

Comment: I don't believe this to be accurate.  I had several Teemo mushrooms cleared (my opponents attacked them, didn't walk through them) that were placed on the altar.  No one had oracles.

Comment: @Toast did they have a Grez's Spectral Lantern? This can be used to clear mushrooms. That being said I have doubts about this too.