# Can Teemo become stealthed while capturing an altar?

Tags: league-of-legends

In response to this question:
[Are stealthed opponents visible when capturing altars on Twisted Treeline?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/91603/are-stealthed-opponents-visible-when-capturing-altars-on-twisted-treeline)

Is it possible for Teemo to activate his passive while capturing an altar?  Or does the act of capturing it prevent his passive?

Comment: need to be tested, but 90% sure it doesn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Teemo's passive activates on lack of action.

Capturing points activates on *proximity*.

If Teemo is on the point, stealthed or otherwise, and no enemies are, it will capture.

It is currently possible to capture points on dominion while stealthed (evelyn, twitch, and Akali, mostly)  because their stealth does not break on continued channel. In Dominion, the capture points are also stealth detectors, which makes this a non-issue. On Twisted Treeline, however, the points do not detect stealth, which makes such stealth captures possible.

Comment: This plus mushrooms makes Teemo a strong 3v3 pick.